# how to align angular mat prefix to a label in a form field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

As you can see on the screenshot guys , I have a prefix for an input but the problem is it is not aligned with the mat label ..is there a way we can modify the mat prefix that it will be align with the mat label ? Thanks for any help and ideas , appreciated.

it should be something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvEiS.png)

#html code

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
            <mat-label>Termination Payment ($)</mat-label>
            <input 
              name="terminationPayment" 
              matInput
              (keyup) = "computeBuyout()"
              mask="separator.0" 
              thousandSeparator=","
              [allowNegativeNumbers]="false"
              [(ngModel)]="dealDispositionFormFields.terminationPayment"
              >
              <span matPrefix *ngIf="dealDispositionFormFields.terminationPayment">$</span>
          </mat-form-field>
```

[current issue - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKNiX.png)

Answer (score 1):

We are going to need to make few changes to the default label wrapper class: shift it left and make sure it is visible. As the label wrapper class is nested quite deeply we need to use mark our overwrite as `::ng-deep`. This modifier will ensure that all sub-components will be effect (be careful with this for the same reason).

Firstly, shift the label left by the size of the icon. By default, `mat-form-field-prefix` (class used by icons) have a size of `12.953px`. By shifting the form label left by this amount it should line up perfectly with the prefix icon.

Next make sure that shifted text would be visible. By default, `mat-form-field-label-wrapper` set overflow to `hidden` so we are going to have to change that. We can achieve this by setting the overflow to visible.

Put together, the class to overwrite the default styling looks like this:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-label-wrapper {
  overflow: visible;
  margin-left: -12.953px;
}
```

Tested against the [example documentation here](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#prefix--suffix). Final result should look like this:

[image: final result]

Comment: Hello , I tried your answer Sir , but why is that when the the field has no input the label hit the corner of the left side of the input field as you can see herehttps://imgur.com/a/j7FTPEv

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/j7FTPEv

Comment: If the field has no input it should still be the same like this https://imgur.com/a/zi8ZHAF , the distance of the label from the left side

Comment: And how do we align the $ sign or the prefix with the input Sir ? cause right now the prefix is a bit lower